# How can we do amide coupling reaction in water?

Tags: organic-chemistry

Does anyone know if it is possible or if there are any protocols for amide coupling in water (and not a normal polar aprotic solvent like DMSO, DCM, ACN, etc.)?

Answer (score 5):

A search on the phrase "Amide Formation in Water" produces a good selection of hits.
Recent papers such as [this](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/acs.orglett.5b01812) and [this](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/op800240d) offer conditions.

From the abstract of [1](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/acs.orglett.5b01812)

> A general and environmentally responsible method for the formation of amide/peptide bonds in an aqueous micellar medium is described. Use of uronium salt (1-cyano-2-ethoxy-2-oxoethylidenaminooxy)dimethylaminomorpholinocarbenium hexafluorophosphate (COMU) as a coupling reagent, 2,6-lutidine, and TPGS-750-M represents mild conditions associated with these valuable types of couplings